# Reading github job environment in a step

Tags: github-actions

I'm using github environments in my github workflow. I want to read the environment name in a step of a job.
According to [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#job-context). It seems that the job context does not have that information. Is it any other way to achieve this?

Basically this is what i want to achieve:

```
jobs:
   deployment:
    name: Deploy to dev
    environment: dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ job.environment.name }}
        # Expected to print 'dev'
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/74910046/736079

Answer (score 0):

you should use: jobs.<job_id>.environment.
See in docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment

Comment: This did not work for me. It says, "Unrecognized named-value: 'jobs'".