# How do I reference the deployment environment name in Github Actions workflow YAML?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-enterprise

I would like to access the deployment environment name in my Github Actions workflow YAML. Here is an example:

```
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: "foobarbaz"
    ...

    steps:
      ...
      - name: Terraform Check Format
        id: terraform-fmt
        # what should I use here instead of "????" to get "foobarbaz"?
        run: terraform -chdir=terraform/stacks/${{ ???? }}/${{ matrix.stack }} fmt -check
```

Answer (score -1):

As `jobs` context is only available in reusable workflows one of working option could be use `env`:

```
name: question-74910046
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74910046/how-do-i-reference-the-deployment-environment-name-in-github-actions-workflow-ya

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
env:
  env_name: production-74910046
  env_url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74910046/how-do-i-reference-the-deployment-environment-name-in-github-actions-workflow-ya

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    environment: 
      name: $env_name
      url: $env_url
    
    steps:
      - name: context information
        run: echo '${{ toJSON(env) }}'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The value from `$env_name` is not passed to the job environment name

Answer (score -1):

You can reference the env using the `environment` key, like so:

```
    test:
        environment: testing
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: Test
        env:
            PORT: ${{ vars.PORT }}
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v4
            - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
              with:
                node-version: ${{ vars.NODE_VERSION }}
                cache: 'npm'
            - run: npm ci
            - run: npm test
```

In my case, I have `testing` env created which includes a var called `PORT` which I want to expose to the process as well.