Access GitHub Actions environment name (not environment variables) from the pipeline steps
We've got GitHub Actions with 3 environments: dev, uat and prod. They've got protection rules defined and we deploy to the environments based on the branch name. This is part of our pipeline.yml:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: ${{ (github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' && 'dev')  ||
                (github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' && 'uat') ||
                (github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && 'prod') }}
    steps:
      [...]
      - name: Build
        run: docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=???what-here??? -t ...
[...]

How can I access the environment name in a later step?
For example when building the container I need to pass --build-arg ENVIRONMENT={dev,uat,prod}.
I can't find it in the env variables, nor in the github.something object. How do I do it?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/74910046/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74719688/3001761

@jonrsharpe looking at the two links there was no working solution present...

This question is similar to: How to get current environment name?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
